# Kubuntu 18.04 freezes on login

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04, kubuntu

I am using Kubuntu 18.04 LTS on Dell hardware. I use the KDE Plasma desktop environment locally, and frequently run XFCE4 remotely with X2Go.

Recently (and suddenly), I can no longer login locally to any graphical environment. On startup, the KDE Plasma greeting screen appears. I can type in my password, but as soon as I click "Login", the screen freezes.

I've seen many other posts with similar titles, but none of the solutions worked for me. So far I've tried:

- Check ownership of ~/.Xauthority (my user is the owner)
- Delete ~/.Xauthority and try logging in again
- Stop sddm service, reboot, start sddm service, try logging in again
- Drop to terminal session (Ctrl+Alt+F3), run `startx` and then `startkde`
  -- this throws `$DISPLAY is not set or cannot connect to the X server`
- removed plasma-desktop and kubuntu-desktop, re-installed, rebooted, tried logging in again

I have no idea what to try next. Open to any suggestions.

Comment: Try sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
and restart when done. See if that helps.

Comment: Remember that a log in, you can press Ctrl-Alt-F1 (F2?) and log in in terminal mode.

Comment: @John I need a graphical environment. The question is what is causing the GUI to freeze when I attempt to log in, and how do I fix it.

Comment: Of course, but if you can log in, repair and then restart, you might get your GUI interface back. My steps are oriented to repairing your system.

Comment: @John As my original post implies, I can already log in. I don't know what to do to repair now. Can you help with that?

Comment: Try the long command string i posted. It has helped me.

Comment: damn the xauthority thing solved a problem that I tried out for long and let me leave the linux installation bare for years after not having a solution, thanks for this list